# How to include php file to wordpress theme(index.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I would like to include cars.php file to index.php theme; the cars.php file is script, which loads data from the server and works as booking system, when I am trying to connect as usual way `include('/.cars.php');`, and check the source code in browser, its there, but no forms appear.

Could be the problem with wordpress engine itself?

Comment: its just my mistake here) in script it looks exactly ./

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a typo `include('/.cars.php');` is likely `include('./cars.php');`

What you have now would look in the root directory for a file called `.cars.php`